# not able to select from &to field in makemytrip in selenium https://www.makemytrip.com/

Tags: selenium

not able to select from &to field in makemytrip in selenium 
https://www.makemytrip.com/

```
driver.get("http://makemytrip.com");


        WebElement source=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fromCity']"));
        source.clear();
        source.sendKeys("MUM");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        source.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);


        WebElement destination=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='toCity']"));
        destination.clear();
        destination.sendKeys("DEL");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        destination.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        destination.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Still not working


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@placeholder='From']
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'

Comment: Can't be the case, that was a working code. Can you try adding a thread.sleep(2000) after You make the get() and see

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@placeholder='From']

*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@placeholder='From']}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https:www.makemytrip.com/");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'From')]"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Delhi, India')]"))).click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'To')]"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Mumbai, India')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select item from list-

try below just for From City-
            driver.get("https:www.makemytrip.com/");

```
        WebElement source=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fromCity']"));
        source.click();
        source.sendKeys("MUM");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        source.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@role='option']//p"));
        for(WebElement ele:list){
            if(ele.getText().contains("Mumbai")){
                ele.click();
            }
        }
```